# how to permit a cross site request with AntiForgeryToken turned on

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

We all know about how to use AntiForgeryToken to avoid a crossed-site request forgery and it's affective enough.

I have a different case (but I think it's common), I have two asp.net mvc web servers, call them A and B.

For some reason, I want to make a post request from the web page A to web server B given the requested action in B have **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]** attribute turned on. How to make it possible?

I see there is a potential with Html.AntiForgery with the domain and virtualpath:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken(salt, domain, virtualpath)
```

Tried this but no luck. Anyone knows how to work this out?

Answer (score 0):

> How to make it possible?

Impossible. The whole security of the anti forgery token relies on cookies and as we have all learned in school, cookies cannot be shared cross domains.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Then a fresh implementation is required. Or is there any library for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Because of cookie permission, for those who encounter the same issue, the answer is possible, iff we host those two site under the same domain.

For example: http: //site1.com and http: //site2.com will not work

http://mainsite.com/site1 and http://mainsite.com/site2 will work.